# Creating symmetric matrix java VRP

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

In fact am working in a vehicle routing problem project, I am trying to generate a problem instance.
Here is an Example where we have a Depot ***"0"*** and Three Stations ***"1","2" and "3"***.
I have created the following table :

```
distdata= new int[stations][(stations+1)]; // where stations is equal to number of stations
```

I filled the Matrix randomly and set the cells having the same row and column index to zero so the distances between the same station and itself is equal to Zero.

```
 System.out.println("Matrix of stations's distances : \n");
                try {
                    BufferedWriter out2 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("StationsDist.bench"));

                    for (int i = 0; i < stations + 1; i++) {
                        System.out.println("\t[" + i + "]");
                    }
                    System.out.println("\n");

                    for (int i = 0; i < stations; i++) {
                        System.out.println("\n[" + (i + 1) + "]");

                        for (int j = 0; j < stations + 1; j++) {
                            if ((i + 1) == j) {

                                dij = 0;
                            } else {
                                dij = (int) (Math.random() * 20) + 1;
                            }
                            System.out.println("\t[" + dij + "]");
                            out2.write(dij + "\t");
                            distdata[i][j] = dij;
                            distdatac[i][j] = dij;

                        }
                        out2.write("\n");
                        System.out.println("\n");
                    }


                    out2.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
```

I got this output :

```
    [0] [1] [2] [3] // [0]-> Depot, [1]-> station 1, [2]-> station 2 ...

[1] [3] [0] [7] [4] // [3] is the distance between station 1 and the depot, and [0] is the null distance between station 1 and itself ...
[2] [1] [9] [0] [6]
[3] [2] [5] [8] [0]
```

The problem is that the distance `distdata[1][2]` should be equal to the distance `distdata[2][1]` because they means the same stations.
I need to create a symmetric matrix or change the table to the following:

```
    [0] [1] [2] [3]

[1] [3] [0] [7] [4]
[2] [1] [7] [0] [6]
[3] [2] [4] [6] [0]
```

Could any one help me please?

Comment: Are you really asking how to create a symetric matrix ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at how I implemented a symmetric and asymmetric transportCost-matrix (https://github.com/jsprit/jsprit/blob/master/jsprit-core/src/main/java/jsprit/core/util/VehicleRoutingTransportCostsMatrix.java). This might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You digged yourself the pit where you fell. Your matrix is `distdata[stations][stations + 1]` and `distdata[i, 0]` gives the distance from i[th] station (whose name is i+1) to depot (whose name is 0). And the distance between stations "1" and "2" for example is `distdata[0][2], and between stations "2" and "1" is ... distdata[1][1] !

So the distance that has to be null is not `distdata[i][i]` but `distdata[i][i+1]`, and the symetry gives `distdata[i][j + 1] == distdata[j][i + 1]`.

IMHO this is really error prone ...

A little improvement : in you inner loop it is enough to loop from 0 to i + 1 provided you
write :

```
distdata[i][j] = d
```

for  j = 0, and

```
distdata[i][j] = d;
distdata[j-1][i+1] = d
```

for j > 0.

But I strongly advise you to accept to lose first raw as build a square matrix so that `distdata[i][i] = 0` and `distdata[i][j] == distdata[j][i]`